# Meltdown checker says AWS and Rackspace is vulnerable - Why?

Tags: cloud-computing, aws, meltdown, spectre

Today I was curious how my vmware environment stacked up against Spectre and Meltdown.  So I ran [spectre-meltdown-checker](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker). It came back clean with

```
7 of 8 variants OK (the failed one is apparently not possible to exploit under VMware)
```

Then I was curious about my cloud stuff so I checked EC2 and RackSpace VMs.  To my surprise they came back with only

```
2 of 8 variants OK
```

That's bad.  Looking at AWS bulletin, they [swear](https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/AWS-2018-013/) that there is no problem.  Why is the script detecting a problem then?  I didn't search RackSpace security bulletins, but I'm assuming they say something similar as AWS. Is the script wrong or is AWS wrong?  How can I really tell other than just taking AWS's word for it?  Also, I don't have any Windows instances, but if I did and I ran [Inspectre](https://www.grc.com/inspectre.htm) would I see the same discrepancy?

If the script is wrong, is there a better script?  Is it because a "better script" would actually have to try the exploit, not just rely on some kind of heuristics?  Where can I find such a script?

PS: You may be wondering which CVE's were ok and which were not.  What I'm referring to when I say "2 of 8 OK" is the summary produced by the tool.  I'm too paranoid to show you which ones, but I bet if you rerun the same tool, you'll get the same result.  Summary looks like this (red/green for KO or OK)

```
SUMMARY: CVE-2017-5753 CVE-2017-5715 CVE-2017-5754 CVE-2018-3640 CVE-2018-3639 CVE-2018-3615 CVE-2018-3620 CVE-2018-3646
```

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker/issues/143

Comment: It helps a bit, in that it explains that depending on kernel, the script may not be able to detect a patch.  But that thread is more than half year old.  My question is, what script exists that correctly verifies AWS/RackSpace patch status?  Or is there a 3rd party that has done the verification and published results?